# CMake SET command not working as expected (CMake not setting value of predefined cached variable)

Tags: cmake, cflags

I'm using CMake in my builds. I'm trying to set compiler flags like this:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-option1 -option2 -option3")
```

however, my build fails because one of the compiler flags is not set.

When I check the value of the variable in CMake-GUI is empty:

[image]

Can someone point out what is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see with cmake-gui is the cache status. You only see there variables that you explicitly cache, or predefined cmake cached variables.

Now, when you do:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-option1 -option2 -option3")
```

You are doing something particular: you are setting a "local" (not cached) variable which has the same name of a predefined cmake cached variable. In C++ it would be like defining a local variable with the same name of a global variable: the local variable will hide your global variable.

From the [`set` documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3aset). (The documentation calls "normal" what I called "local")

> Both types can exist at the same time with the same name but different
>   values. When ${FOO} is evaluated, CMake first looks for a normal
>   variable 'FOO' in scope and uses it if set. If and only if no normal
>   variable exists then it falls back to the cache variable 'FOO'.

**You are already effectively setting CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG, and the compiler will use the flags you have specified**. You can check it with:

```
message(STATUS "CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG = ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
```

So, your building is failing for another reason. Check which command line make generates: `make VERBOSE=1`.

By the way, I suggest you *append* your flags to the predefined ones, by doing:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG} -option1 -option2 -option3")
```

Also consider using the other predefined variable `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`, in case you want those settings to be propagated to all build types.

---

**Edit:**
After some iterations it turned out the problem was that the build type (`CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`) was not set from cmake. This can either be done through the cmake-gui interface, or adding something like `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` or `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` to the cmake command line.

Comment: Hi Antonio, big thanks for the answer, I didn’t put in my question the actual flags I'm using. I'll check the VERBOSE option and I'll tell you

Comment: Hi @Antonio, I set verbose as you said,  my build is failing because the -std=gnu99 flag is not set in the compiler. However I'm setting this flag as you suggested in your example in my cmake file. Still no work :(. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @ElMarce Which kind of files are you building? C or C++?

Comment: When I put the option in the GUI (therefore in the cache value I guess) the build succeed

Comment: @ElMarce That's weird. Which cmake version are you using?

Comment: Cmake: 2.8.12.2. I'm in linux ubuntu 14.0.4

Comment: @ElMarce I have posted a relevant part of the documentation, I confirm there must be something to fix in your CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75780/discussion-between-el-marce-and-antonio).